# Linux command-line music player to play mp3 streams

Tags: linux, software-rec, mp3, music, streaming

I'm looking for a console music player that can take an http mp3 stream from MPD as input. Ability to remotely control this player would be an added bonus.

Also, do you know if any of these players can be configured to routinely check the URL for a music stream, and play the stream when it is active ? i.e. so I do not have to manually start up the player when I start up the MPD stream.

This would be running on the console inside a screen session, so technically I can run curses-based players if I absoutely had to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/) can play mp3 and it can play http streams, so maybe that is a possible solution? Probably there are better options available, but maybe usable?

Comment: I went with this suggestion after failing to get vlc to work as I wanted. It's worked great for me.

Answer (score 1):

[cmus](http://cmus.sourceforge.net/) seems to be able to play 'MP3 and Ogg streaming (Shoutcast/Icecast)' I asume that what one get from MPD ?

cmus is ncurses based